# Solution of a recursive relation (only for certain parameters?)

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion

Consider the coefficients $C_p$ ($p=1,2,...$) defined by the recursive relation

$(p-E)\; C_p =  A\left(\sqrt{p} \; C_{p-1} + \sqrt{p+1} \; C_{p+1}\right)$

where A is a fixed parameter E is an unknown parameter. 
I'm trying to understand

(1) if it is possible to find an explicit expression for $C_p$ and

(2) if, for some values of $E$, the sum of the series $C_p$ converges to a finite value.

(The second requirement is due to the fact that later I want to re-normalize the coefficients such that $\sum_p^\infty |C_p|^2=1$)

So far I have tried to guess the solution by requiring these two conditions to be valid at the same time

(1) $\sqrt{p} \; C_{p-1} \propto (p-E) C_p$

(2) $\sqrt{p+1} \; C_{p+1} \propto (p-E) C_p$

For each condition I can derive a recursive solution for $C_p$, but these two solutions seem to be incompatible with each other.

Does anybody have some suggestion on how to tackle this problem?

Comment: The solution sequences make a vector space of dimension two. If you have two solutions where neither one is a constant multiple of the other, you have a basis, and can write out all solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you be more specific? In my case I do not have two valid solutions. I just heuristically try to solve it by requiring separately that each of the two members of the right-hand side of the first equation are proportional to the left-hand side.

Comment: Note that I edited my first post to clarify better my question.

Comment: Alright. If you have $x_{n+2} = f(n) x_{n+1} + g(n) x_n,$ one special sequence is that with $x_0 = 0, x_1 = 1,$ while the other special sequence is the one with  $x_0 = 1, x_1 = 0.$ I thought you knew two distinct solutions which would have finished the problem. However , if you just have some sort of estimates of what a solution with certain growth conditions ought to be like, then you have a long way to go.  Suggest you do some computer modelling, it might give some ideas.